# Dictionary with multiple keys isn't working as expected

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, foreach

I'm making a console program where I've got multiple values mapped to `dictionary` `keyLookup`. I'm using if commands that use the key to output some `console.writeline = ("stuff");` but it only works if I have the value and the key the same (in the dictionary). I don't know why this is. I've been mucking about with `list` and `foreach` and some variables trying to figure out what I've done wrong but even though it continues to work how it works now it still doesn't work how I want.

Also if I have a word in my `console.readline();` that isn't in my dictionary the whole thing crashes. Which I don't want, and I'm not sure of why its doing that either as at some point it didn't. Also my `mathFunction` dictionary works just how I want my `keyLookup` dictionary to work. Though I think the difference is in how I'm using a list to cross reference through `keyLookup`.

```
class MainClass
    {
        public static string Line;
        static string foundKey;
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                if (Line == null)
                {Console.WriteLine ("Enter Input"); }
                WordChecker ();
            }
    }
    public static void WordChecker()
    {
        string inputString = Console.ReadLine ();
        inputString = inputString.ToLower();  

        string[] stripChars = { ";", ",", ".", "-", "_", "^", "(", ")", "[", "]",
            "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "\n", "\t", "\r" };

        foreach (string character in stripChars)
        {
            inputString = inputString.Replace(character, "");
        }
        // Split on spaces into a List of strings
        List<string> wordList = inputString.Split(' ').ToList();
        // Define and remove stopwords
        string[] stopwords = new string[] { "and", "the", "she", "for", "this", "you", "but" };

        foreach (string word in stopwords)
        {
            // While there's still an instance of a stopword in the wordList, remove it.
            // If we don't use a while loop on this each call to Remove simply removes a single
            // instance of the stopword from our wordList, and we can't call Replace on the
            // entire string (as opposed to the individual words in the string) as it's
            // too indiscriminate (i.e. removing 'and' will turn words like 'bandage' into 'bdage'!)
            while ( wordList.Contains(word) )
            {
                wordList.Remove(word);
            }
        }
        // Create a new Dictionary object
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        // Loop over all over the words in our wordList...

        foreach (string word in wordList)
        {
            // If the length of the word is at least three letters...

            if (word.Length >= 3) 
            {

                // ...check if the dictionary already has the word.

                if ( dictionary.ContainsKey(word) )
                {

                    // If we already have the word in the dictionary, increment the count of how many times it appears

                    dictionary[word]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Otherwise, if it's a new word then add it to the dictionary with an initial count of 1

                    dictionary[word] = 1;
                }
            }

            List<string> dicList = new List<string>();
            dicList = dictionary.Keys.ToList ();

            Dictionary<string, string> keyLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            keyLookup["hey"] = "greeting";
            keyLookup["hi"] = "greeting";
            keyLookup["greeting"] = "greeting";
            keyLookup["math"] = "math";
            keyLookup["calculate"] = "math";
            keyLookup["equation"] = "math";

            foundKey = keyLookup[word];

            List<string> keyList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string keyWord in dicList)
            {
                if(keyWord == foundKey)
                {keyList.Add (keyWord); }
            }

            foreach (string mKey in keyList)
            {
            if(mKey == "greeting")
            {Greetings ();}

            if (mKey == "math") 
            {Math ();}
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Math()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("What do you want me to math?");
        Console.WriteLine ("input a number");
        string input = Console.ReadLine ();

        decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal (input);
        Console.WriteLine("Tell me math function");
        string mFunction = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine ("tell me another number");
        string inputB = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal (inputB);

        Dictionary<string, string> mathFunction = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        mathFunction["multiply"] = "multiply";
        mathFunction["times"] = "multiply";
        mathFunction["x"] = "multiply";
        mathFunction["*"] = "multiply";
        mathFunction["divide"] = "divide";
        mathFunction["/"] = "divide";
        mathFunction["subtract"] = "subtract";
        mathFunction["minus"] = "subtract";
        mathFunction["-"] = "subtract";
        mathFunction["add"] = "add";
        mathFunction["+"] = "add";
        mathFunction["plus"] = "add";

        string foundKey = mathFunction[mFunction];

        if (foundKey == "add")
        {
            Console.WriteLine (a + b);
        }
        else if (foundKey == "subtract")
        {
            Console.WriteLine (a - b);
        }
        else if (foundKey == "multiply")
        {
            Console.WriteLine (a * b);
        }
        else if (foundKey == "divide")
        {
            Console.WriteLine (a / b);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("not a math");
        }
    }

    public static void Greetings()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You said hello");
    }
}'
```

Comment: This is a very convoluted question. What are you trying to achieve exactly? There is definitely a way to do all of this with *far, far* fewer lines of code using LINQ, if you can just explain a bit more clearly what result you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that I can type lines into in a 'conversational fashion' and have it grab keywords from what I say and execute functions. For example the math I have it doing now. Later on I want to try to have it do more complex things but first I need to get it reading my input properly.

yeah I know it could be done in less code. I'm a total noob though :)

Comment: I was going look into this further, but this code needs a total re-write.  I found two errors and a couple places you could use predicate functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through the dictionary differently (Dont use ToList-Function).

Try this instead:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair kvp (Of String, String) In testDictionary)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Key:" + kvp.Key + " Value:" + kvp.Value);
}
```

And your application is crashing if the word doesn't match, because of this code (You're not creating a new entry that way):

```
// Otherwise, if it's a new word then add it to the dictionary with an initial count of 1
dictionary[word] = 1;
```

**EDIT:** I was wrong about that `dictionary[word] = 1` would not create a new element. It's perfectly fine like this.

Comment: I'll have to do some research before I try it out. I'm not familiar with `KeyValuePair` `debug` or `Next` yet. Thanks for the tip though. I'll definitelly do some reading and try to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: You can also use GetEnumerator and loop through it that way, if you're more familiar with this.

Comment: `dictionary[word] = 1;` is correct. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx . `If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException, and **a set operation creates a new element with the specified key**.`

Comment: @AmazingMrBrock this code sample is in VB.net, not C#. There's no `Next` keyword in C#, the equivalent C# code is `foreach(var kvp in testDictionary) { Debug.WriteLine("Key: " + kvp.Key + " Value: " + kvp.Value); }`

Answer (score 0):

> `foundKey = keyLookup[word];`

If `word` doesn't exist in keyLookup then it will crash.

> `string foundKey = mathFunction[mFunction];`

if `mFunction` doesn't exist in mathFunction then it will crash.

---

If you're trying to make this a "conversational" program, then the word look-up **is** the most important part.  You don't use predicates or LINQ, both can make string functions **extremely** easy.  Currently you use a Dictionary.  Why not use Lists for each keyword?

```
List<string> GreetingKeywords;
GreetingKeywords.Add("hello"); // ...

List<string> MathKeywords;
MathKeywords.Add("math"); // ...

foreach (var word in dicList)
{
  if (GreetingKeywords.Contains(word))
    { Greetings(); }
  if (MathKeywords.Contains(word))
    { Maths(); }
}
```

I'd suggest you read up on predicate and List/Dictionary functions such as Find, IndexOf, etc. etc.  That knowledge is invaluable to C#.